# Is it possible to use wildcard App Service Certificate across subscriptions?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We bought a wildcard Azure App Service Certificate through the Azure portal with the intent of reusing the certificate across websites and environments. While setting up the staging environment I tried to reuse the certificate without luck. I tried importing the certificate through the portal, but it requires to be in the same subscription. Furthermore, I tried exporting the certificate through the portal and PowerShell without luck. Is it possible to use the App Service Certificate on another subscription?

Comment: Please develop "While setting up the staging environment I tried to reuse the certificate without luck.": What did you try and how do you see that it does not work?

Comment: @ThibaultD from the question above: "I tried importing the certificate through the portal, but it requires to be in the same subscription. Furthermore, I tried exporting the certificate through the portal and PowerShell without luck."